# What is the proper way to instantiate a ConstraintLayout Object?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

at the beginning of my activity, I wrote:

```
private static ConstraintLayout cl;
```

then in onCreate, I wrote:

```
cl = new ConstraintLayout(myActivity.this);
```

The reason I am doing this is that I want to use

```
cl.addView(myView);
```

wherever I can in my activity.

BUT, there is a huge problem, if I leave the program as the above set-up, no view will be added at all, but also no crashes.

If I want to add my view, I need to do this:

```
cl = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_design);
```

So, just do this then, what's the big deal?

The problem is that:

1. I can only use that in a "branch steps" of my activity, I cannot use it anywhere major, I'm sorry I don't know how to put it better. For example, I can put it in a switch-case code section of my activity, but NEVER in something major like onCreate(), or strangely this very line of code will "nullify" the cl, that is, strange enough, after executing:

   cl = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_design);

the cl will go from something to "null" in debug window. This happens when I put this very line in "onCreate()"

But the problem isn't over:

2. I can only use that line ONCE yet I MUST use that line.

In other words, I must use:
    cl = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_design);

but I cannot use it in another "branch" place (my apologies again for not knowing the proper terminology), if I do, there will be a

> "java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."

mistake. And if I don't call it for a second time, cl will ALWAYS be "null" when I use it.

I am so frustrated! How should I properly instantiate this cl object so I can use it conveniently anywhere???

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues. I recommend reading/watching a tutorial on building android apps.

At its core ConstraintLayout is a view.
Views have to be on the screen to see them.
setContentView(cl) puts it on the screen. 
findViewById allows you to find objects on the screen

ConstraintLayout is also a ViewGroup which means it can contain and layout other views.

For ConstraintLayout to layout (position and size) it must be constrained.
(look at tutorials on ConstraintLayout.

If you want a simple brute force putting up buttons (cl.addView(myView))
use a layout that has a fixed layout LinearLayout().

Also storing a layout (subclass of ViewGroup) in a static variable is a bad idea because it will leak. For better understanding of this read about "Android Activity lifecycle".